# Pympress sometimes hangs on Windows - caching issue?

Tags: python, config

I've recently discovered `pyimpress` and I want to use it with my `beamer` presentations which so far I've shown using `SumatraPDF`.  However, with the presentation I'm currently working on, `pyimpress` sometimes hangs.  It doesn't react immediately to the arrow key for the next slide but might take several seconds instead and is unresponsive in the meantime.  I wonder if this is an issue with the caching mechanism.  I've read that this can be changed using the configuration file, but I couldn't find any further information about its syntax and there doesn't seem to be a configuration file coming with the program.  Any hints?

FWIW, I'm on Windows 10, the PDF is about 20MB and consists of 207 pages plus notes (but not movies or such).  Nothing interesting in the log file.  The program is in `%AppData%\Local\Programs\pympress-1.8.5-x86_64.msi`